# Router slows down after some time, only over wifi, no admin, router reboot helps

Tags: networking, router, reboot, connection

Problem's in the title.

Additional info:
Router - TL-WR1043ND (TP-Link), latest firmware.
Wireless security - WPA2/AES.
OS - OpenSuSE 12.2 and 12.1 (two computers).

After reboot everything is fine, after high net load (I think) it slows down and router admin becomes unavailable, although internet is still reachable, just VERY slow...

Comment: When did this start? Are you rebooting the computer or the router?

Comment: Not sure when it started, I used wired connection for a long time.
Rebooting router, it happens on two computers, so the problem is at least in the router...

Comment: Hmm, it sounds a lot like what I [recently started experiencing](http://superuser.com/questions/478359) with a D-Link router. I’m wondering if maybe there is a new malware that triggers a vulnerability in older routers’ firmwares…

Comment: I'm on Linux, no malware here :)

Comment: I’m not talking about on the computer, I’m talking about on the Internet. For example, a worm may scan a series of ports, and the scan may be configured badly (purposely or accidentally) which then triggers a bug in the router firmware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try an alternate open source firmware like OpenWrt, which is compatible with this router.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd

Comment: +1 My Linksys routers suffered the same thing. Moving to dd-wrt fixed it for me. :)

Comment: Marking this as a right one because this is what I'm going to do :)

Comment: Yep, definitely solved my issue... Some other issues appeared though :/