# Internet connection is lost very often

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have recently connected to some fiber infrastructure for internet.
I am connected to it with my laptop and my phone, via a TP-LINK **TL-WDR4300** router.

I often encounter connection losses, like various download speeds drop to 0 occasionally, online games get "disconnected" because connection to server is lost, and it's really really annoying.

I read through [This](https://superuser.com/questions/478359/bizarre-and-very-specific-internet-connection-loss) question, but it has no accepted answer and plus my connection only drops momentarily for a few milliseconds and immediately comes back.

The connection losses occur randomly, but at the same time on my phone and my laptop, both on 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands, so I can rule out the laptop and phone's part.

I need to know whether it's the router's fault or the infrastructure, or the internet provider.

- I know some of you will advise me to switch or bypass the router to see if the issue persists, **but this will not provide certain indication so I do not want to get into this**

Is there a way to determine for sure who is the culprit in this situation?

I'm not too much into systems, so all I could think about so far was to `tracert` to Google and then do a simultaneous `ping` to each point in the route and wait for a connection drop to see which one times out, but of course Murphy's Law hit again and I haven't had a single connection drop since.

Comment: Do "tracert [ip] -t >> PingLog.txt" and it will trace to file, you can then go back and look at when / where it dropped.

Comment: @Linef4ult tracert has no **-t** switch, are you sure that this is what you meant?

Comment: guys dont downvote a question if you cannot solve the issue. this is a legit question about a scenario which is not described in any other question, and could happen to any of you as well in the future.

Comment: People tend to downvote if they believe the question is of poor quality, if you get those notifications its usually a suggestion you should be adding detail.

Comment: @Linef4ult what details would you advise me to add to contribute to the point of the question?

Answer (score 1):

[mtr](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr) might be helpful for this. It's a kind of continuous traceroute.

By the way, any drop for only "a few milliseconds" should not cause TCP connection drops or server disconnects. I imagine it would have to be at least several seconds long before anything notices. The only way an interruption of less than a second would be noticed is if your machine's local link goes down (that is, if you get disassociated from your Wi-Fi AP).

Comment: thanks, i will try it out. this is a really weird case i got here, because my machine is not getting disconnected from the wifi at all, neither are the mobile devices that i've tried. on all of them the connection drops simultaneously and for just a moment, like everything is still conencted and still works but shows the symptoms from my question. i really have no idea what could cause such a thing...